# How can I stop the JTextField from taking up my whole JFrame?

Tags: java, swing

I have code written to create a JFrame which holds a game, but I need to add a TextField. So far I have been able to add the whole field but it takes up the entire frame. I'm a bit confused looking at other examples, so I thought I would ask if anyone could prompt me in the right direction a bit with my code.

```
public class Window extends Canvas {

    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5360723068750368974L;

    public Window( int width, int height, String title, Game game){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);

        JTextField username = new JTextField(10);



        //Sets minimum maximum and default window size as the same, so the window is always the same size
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        //Allows the x button on the window to close the program
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        //Prevents the window from being resizable
        frame.setResizable(false);
        //Location of the window is not relative to anything
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //Tells the frame what it will contain
        frame.add(game);
        frame.add(username);
        //Makes the frame visible
        frame.setVisible(true);
        //calls game start method
        game.start();
    }
}
```

The output for the code without the JTextField:
[image: Standard game window]

VS with the JTextField:

[image: text field]

I want the text box to only take up a small portion of the screen somewhere in the middle.

Comment: The default layout manager for the content pane of the frame is a BorderLayout. You are attempting to add 2 components to the CENTER. You can't do this. Only the last component added will be displayed. Add your game to the "CENTER" and the text field to the "PAGE_START". Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for a basic example. You can also nest panels with different layout managers to achieve more complex layouts.

Comment: Thank you, looking at the documentation I'm not sure what type I want to use, as  it seems that they mostly work by placing elements adjacent to eachother, whereas for mine, ideally I want the text box to appear over the middle of the existing game.

Comment: Well having a text field in the middle of the game would ruin the game. So I'm guessing you just want to add the text box temporarily to prompt the user for information. In this case you can use a `JOptionPane`. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on "How to Make Dialogs" for more information. If you really want the text field in the middle of the game, then add the text field to the game panel not the frame. Swing components have a parent/child relationship.

Comment: Yeah my plan was to use an if to render the box if the game is won, as the box is going to be used to prompt the user for a username for the scoreboard

Comment: Ok, so I added a JOptionPane and it seems to work, it doesn't place it over the existing window and replaces it temporarily instead but I can definitely work with it

Comment: Read the API. You need to specify the frame as the "parent". I believe its the first parameter of the `showInputDialog(....)`.

Answer (score 0):

Have You Tried
`textField.setBounds();`?

Usage With Example:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int PositionX = 0,PositionY = 0,SizeX = 450,SizeY = 450;
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
        JTextField textField = new JTextField();
        frame.add(textField);
        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setLayout(null);
        textField.setBounds(PositionX,PositionY,SizeX,SizeY);
        textField.setVisible(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Or you Can Use JInternalFrame And Implement The TextField In There.

EDIT: I have made corrections to the code thanks to the below comment

Comment: (1-) Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. It is the job of the layout manager to set the size/location of the component, so the bounds you set will be ignored. There are so many other things wrong with the  code: 1) components should be added to the frame BEFORE the frame is made visible. 2) no need to invoke setVisible(...) on the text field since components are visible by default. 3) variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: Hii, The Variable Names Is Just To Make People UNderstand Where Should They Put The Numbers For Their Required needs

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue in the end by using a JOptionPane instead which appears at the start of the game.

If anyone else reading has a similar issue but does not want to use an option pane, you can instead set a layout for your window and add components to it in a way that they do not overlap eachother.